# How do I know if a fade effect is occurring?

Tags: jquery, fade

I did a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbpjuykq/), the idea is:

The function takes an element (el), and if "el" is in fadeIn or in fadeOut then retun true, else return false. Is it possible?

```
function fadeIsRunning( el ){
    /* How to achieve this ? */
    return false || true;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

```js
var obj = $("div");

$("#fade").on("click", function(){
 obj.fadeToggle(3000);
});

$("#decision").on("click", function(){
 if (fadeIsRunning(obj)) {
  console.log( "Fade is running" );
 }
 else {
  console.log( "Fade isn't running" );
 }
});


function fadeIsRunning( el ){
 /* How to achieve this ? */
    return false || true;
}
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: #99f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="fade" id="fade" />
<input type="button" value="decision" id="decision" />
<div>X</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/), `.is(':animated')`, to determine if the element is actively being faded.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ak694c3/)

```
function fadeIsRunning( el ){
    return $(el).is(':animated');
}
```

References:

- [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)
- [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/g8p62e2m/)***

Inspect the fx [queue <sup>jQuery</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/) in jquery to see the element's progress. If it is in the fx queue and fading, its status will be "inprogress"

```
function fadeIsRunning( el ){
 return $.queue(el[0]) == "inprogress";
}
```

Comment: Wow.. you got it too! You guys are incredible !